# Static library file generated from Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin.ios, static-libraries, xamarin

I have a C# project which have all the business logic files. So i need to use those files in ios project. i,e I need to create a framework or library from '.cs' files(C# files).
Is it possible to achieve this by using 'Xamarin'?

I have tried creating the static library project in 'Xamarin Studio'. But i can't find the '.a' lib file generated when i build the project.

Can i create a static library .a file from Xamarin?. If so, then can i use that project in my iOS xcode projects?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no, you can't create a static native library out of a managed project.

But that doesn't mean you can't call your managed call from the native part, but at the end, your project will still be a Xamarin.iOS project.